# Protection against user textarea input

Tags: php, html, forms, session, cookies

Do I need to do anything special to protect myself against user input from a textarea when the input is simply stored in a session cookie?

Im selling products that can be engraved with custom text. The user is "supposed" to enter the text they would like engraved into a textarea, and this text is stored in a session cookie along with the item they chose & some other data.

Right now, I use nl2br before storing it in the session cookie, then stripslashes when I display it back out onto the page.

Do I need to do anything else to protect myself from malicious code (i.e. htmlentities, etc)?

Thanks for your input (no pun intended!)

Comment: Well as long as you don't run into problems, why do you ask? You are aware what you're doing, aren't you?

Comment: It works, I just don't know if I'm leaving myself open to any hacking attempts, etc.

Comment: How could you? Maybe the engraving machine has a security issue if you pass certain strings to it. Which model are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Validate the input if you only want to allow certain characters such as a-z 0-9. If you don't want characters like `<` and `>` then validate.

As a general rule of thumb, store the input as it was entered, and do any processing before it is printed to a page or other medium. By processing, I mean run it through `nl2br()` and `htmlentities()`.

Usually it's better to store the data in a neutral form i.e not processed for HTML etc because you may want to output the data to some other form in future, like XML, web services, in which case it will need to be processed differently.

Store it in a session variable, not a cookie. A session variable is stored on the server and is not accessible by browsers or anyone else. If you store it in a cookie, it can be tampered with and you will have to re-validate the input every time you want to access it because it might have changed.

If you eventually store the data in a database, you'll need to escape it for SQL Injection. The method of that will vary depending on which library is used to interface with the database, but parameterised queries or prepared statements is preferable.

Comment: Storing the data in a neutral form does mean everyone who displays that data has to a) realize the data may be malicious and b) do the security right each time. But I have dealt with data processed for HTML before and I think you're right.

Answer (score 2):

The first most obvious chance for attack would be direct HTML input. Imagine someone input `<script src="http://malicious.com/ddos.js" />` into your textarea. Would your PHP code output that in a way that would make it run the .js code?

Second, how does the data get to the engraver? Most common would be that it's stored in a database for later use, or maybe emailed to a queue of work for the engraver.

If you're putting into a database, you'll want to look into a wrapper like PDO that can handle cleaning input.

If you're emailing it to yourself or someone else then you'll need to take care to avoid putting dangerous information in there. I believe php's mail() function will automaticlly keep the `$message` from making changes to the headers. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

If you have some other method, let us know and there may be other concerns.

Answer (score 1):

You should run `htmlspecialchars()` before you display the variable in the textarea box.

This will make sure that possibly evil HTML code is safely displayed inside the textarea instead of being executed.

All other places you show the variable, eg. in an e-mail or an admin interface, you should run `htmlspecialchars()` on it as well.

Simularily, also remember to escape the variable if saving to a database, so people are not able to mess with your database query.

(An alternative approach to doing `htmlspecialchars()` upon display, would be running a `strip_tags()` on the user's input before it is stored in the session variable. But sanitizing input on *display* as suggested above is a more robust way of thinking, IMHO.)